# Vuetify expansion panels set value with sessionStorage and do not trigger watcher

Tags: vue.js, session, vuetify.js, watch

I am passing from a parent component expand prop as true.
in my component, I have an expansion-panels vuetify component with v-model="panel"

```
  <v-expansion-panels
    :focusable="!totalCount > 0"
    v-model="panel"
    multiple
    v-if="!isLoading"
  >
```

I am declaring my prop here

```
  props: {
    expand: Boolean,
  }
```

And in my data, I use an array with an index to open or close my panel (I only have one)

```
panel: this.expand ? [0] : [1],
```

What I want to achieve is to store the user's choice to expand or not this panel, the first time he lands on the page it should be expanded but then when he navigates on the app and he decided to collapse the panel when he gets back the panel is still collapsed.

But as I want the user to see the expanded panel every day his choice should be removed after 12 hours.

So I decided to use sessionStorage and also store a date and when mounting the component check if my date is less or more than the time when the choice was set

```
  mounted: function () {
    this.getTimesheetsKpis();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("analyticsSession") !== null) {
      var analyticsSession = JSON.parse(
        sessionStorage.getItem("analyticsSession")
      );
      var currentDate = moment(new Date());
      var sessionDate = analyticsSession.date;

      var duration = moment.duration(currentDate.diff(sessionDate));
      var hours = duration.asHours();
      console.log("hours", hours);
      var secs = duration.asSeconds();
      console.log("secs", secs);

      if (secs > 45 /* hours >= 12 */) {
        console.log("session expired");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("analyticsSession");
      } else {
        this.panel = analyticsSession.panel;
      }
    }
  },
```

In my methods, I use a function to set the session storage item like that

```
    setSessionStorage() {
      console.log("session storage function triggered");
      var today = moment(new Date());
      var analyticsSession = {
        date: today,
        panel: this.panel,
      };

      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "analyticsSession",
        JSON.stringify(analyticsSession)
      );
    },
```

And I watch if the panel state changes to trigger that function

```
  watch: {
        panel: {
      handler(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log(oldVal.length, newVal.length)
        
        if(oldVal.length !== newVal){
          console.log("panel watcher", newVal, oldVal);
      this.setSessionStorage();
        }

      }
    },
```

My issue is that the watcher will trigger every time I navigate back to this component and will trigger the `setSessionStorage` function I guess it's because the expanded value is set to true and the watcher will compare with this value.

How can I avoid that?